# How do you locate/check the letter of each word in a file to see if it is a vowel or consonant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Basically, I have a text file. I need to be able to check each word in the text file to see if the word starts with a vowel or consonant.

I used this code to read and then split the file into a list of words:

```
with open("textfile.txt") as file:
     text = file.read()
     text = text.split()
```

However from this, I am unsure how to drill down to the letter level and make the vowel/consonant check on each word. How do I check the first letter of each word in the list to see if it is a vowel or consonant?

This post tells me how to check for vowels:
[checking if the first letter of a word is a vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379243/checking-if-the-first-letter-of-a-word-is-a-vowel)

So my question really is, how do I make the check on the word/letter level?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi hilbert!

can you share the contents of your file?
I have a suspicion that you need to split by line `text.split('\n')`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string, alike any other sequence in Python, is subscriptable.

So for a word, you can get the first letter by doing `word[0]`

Then, from other other post you already know, how to check if it is vowel or consonant.

You can do that for every word in your text by looping over them.

```
words_starting_with_vowels = []
words_starting_with_consonants = []
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
for word in text: # loop over all words
    lower_case_letter = word[0].lower()
    if lower_case_letter in vowels:
        words_starting_with_vowels.append(word)
    else:
        words_starting_with_consonants.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the first character in your word and compare it against an array of vowels, or you can use the startswith() method:

```
vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')
if text.startswith(vowels):
    print("starts with vowel")
else:
    print("starts with consonant")
```

Answer (score 0):

text.split() will return an array of words. You need to iterate over this and check if each word starts with a vowel.

```
for word in text:
    if word.startswith(('A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u')):
        print("It's a vowel") # Or do something else with the word
    else:
        print("Not a vowel")
```

Instead of `word.startswith()` You could also use the solution in the post you linked.

```
for word in text:
    if word[0].lower() in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        print("It's a vowel")
    else:
        print("Not a vowel")
```