# Identify if a word in a list starts with a vowel

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I need to identify if these words start with a vowel or not.

```
year= ["january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"]
vowels = "aeiou"

for month in range(len(year)):
    if month.startswith(vowels):
         if_vowel = "Yes"
    else:
         if_vowel = "No"
print("Does the month of {0} start with a vowel? {1}".format(year[i],if_vowel)
```

Ideally,it would print Yes or No depending if the month starts with a vowel

Comment: None of the month names start with "aeiouy" (which is what you were originally testing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [checking if the first letter of a word is a vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379243/checking-if-the-first-letter-of-a-word-is-a-vowel)

Comment: Hi! Please don't forget to include an actual question in your post! It's not clear to me what portion of this problem you are actually having trouble with. Does the interpreter throw an exception (that you didn't expect)? Please include that! Did it return unexpected output? Please include what was shown and what you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

```
for month in year:
    print(f"Does the month of {month} start with a vowel? {'Yes' if month[0] == 'e' else 'No'}")
```

You may use Python3's **f-String** for much easier formatting. Then, within the f-String, you may use a **Conditional Expression** like returning "Yes" if the first letter of the month is "e" or returning "No" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you iterate over `year` instead of the indecies `range(len(year))`. Then you can check if the first character `month[0]` is a value with `month[0] in vowels`.

```
year= ["january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"]
vowels = "aeiouy"

for month in year:
    if month[0] in vowels:
         if_vowel = "Yes"
    else:
         if_vowel = "No"
    
    print("Does the month of {0} start with a vowel? {1}".format(month,if_vowel))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check if the first alphabet in the name of the month starts with a vowel. or not. Iterating over indices will help you in getting the expected output. And 'y' is not a vowel. So updated your code.

```
year= ["january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"]
vowels = "aeiou"

for i in range(len(year)):
    if year[i][0] in vowels:
         if_vowel = "Yes"
    else:
         if_vowel = "No"
    print("Does the month of {0} start with a vowel? {1}".format(year[i],if_vowel))
```

Output:

```
Does the month of january start with a vowel? No
Does the month of february start with a vowel? No
Does the month of march start with a vowel? No
Does the month of april start with a vowel? Yes
Does the month of may start with a vowel? No
Does the month of june start with a vowel? No
Does the month of july start with a vowel? No
Does the month of august start with a vowel? Yes
Does the month of september start with a vowel? No
Does the month of october start with a vowel? Yes
Does the month of november start with a vowel? No
Does the month of december start with a vowel? No
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november",
        "december"]
vowels = ("a", "o", "e", "i", "u", "y")

for month in year:
    if month.startswith(vowels):
        if_vowel = "Yes"
    else:
        if_vowel = "No"
    print("Does the month of {0} start with a vowel? {1}".format(month, if_vowel))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november",
        "december"]
vowels = ("a", "o", "e", "i", "u", "y")

for month in year:
    if month[0] in vowels:
        if_vowel = "Yes"
    else:
        if_vowel = "No"
    print("Does the month of {0} start with a vowel? {1}".format(month, if_vowel))
```